# Dropdown List not saving data to session

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am having trouble saving a session for a DropDownList that should work across multiple pages. This is the code I have for it right now:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ddlOffice.SelectedValue = Session("Office")
End Sub
```

And this is the code I have for assigning the value...

```
Protected Sub ddlOffice_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ddlOffice.SelectedIndexChanged
    Session("Office") = ddlOffice.SelectedItem.Value.ToString
End Sub
```

I checked with a breakpoint for the last value and its definitely passed correctly - the value passed for the load parameter was "2", which is correct, but the SelectedIndexChanged session value seems to default back to 1. Always. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control event handlers are fired **after** the `Page_Load` event. So is the `ddlOffice_SelectedIndexChanged` event handler. The code `ddlOffice.SelectedValue = Session("Office")` has ran in the `Page_Load` phase and the session then has the old value. To work this arround, change the `ddlOffice_SelectedIndexChanged` as follows:

```
Protected Sub ddlOffice_SelectedIndexChanged(
         ByVal sender As Object, 
         ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ddlOffice.SelectedIndexChanged
     Session("Office") = ddlOffice.SelectedItem.Value.ToString
     ddlOffice.SelectedValue = ddlOffice.SelectedItem.Value.ToString
End Sub
```

and also, add a check in the `Page_Load` event:

```
If Not Page.IsPostback
    ddlOffice.SelectedValue = Session("Office")
```

The latter is not mandatory, but you do not need this in postbacks, since the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler will do the job

Answer (score 0):

You seem convinced that the SelectedIndexChange event is the problem but I thought I'd mention this:

If you put this line at the very top of the Page_Load, as you showed:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ddlOffice.SelectedValue = Session("Office")
End Sub
```

It won't find anything since the data that should be populated in the dropdown hasn't been bound yet. You need to set the selected value after whatever code you use to bind the data to the dropdown unless the items in the DDL are static (defined in the markup)

Answer (score 0):

Move the assignment for the selected value into the DataBound event for the drop down list, and cast the session variable to a string as follows:

```
ddlOffice.SelectedValue = (string)(Session("Office"))
```